# jquery keyup ignore non-changing characters

Tags: jquery, events, keyboard, keycode, onkeyup

I'm trying to get an event to fire whenever a contenteditable div is changed using keyup. Unfortunately it's also catching things like moving the caret with the arrow keys. I only want it to spot actual changes though.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977642/how-to-know-if-keyup-is-a-character-key-jquery) question, which seems similar, but the solution on there doesn't work for things like linebreaks. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to cache the length outside the handler then compare the current length of the textarea against your cached length.  If they differ then you can assume the key that was pressed added content to the textarea.  Hope this helps.

```
var textarea = $('textarea').get(0),
    length = $(textarea).val().length;

$(textarea).keyup(function() {
   if($(this).val().length != length) {

     //do something


     //cache new length
     length = $(this).val().length();
   }
});
```

Comment: $(this).length always equals 1. Should be $(this).text().length

Comment: I totally messed that up - I forgot to add .val()  I'm going to take a coffee break for that one.

Comment: Or val(), that works too. Don't worry, I've had plenty of those moments. :O

Comment: Nevermind, val() doesn't work. Only text does...but length doesn't change in linebreaks for some reason. :S

Comment: @Stephen have you checked the fiddle out yet?  It's working there.

Comment: Yeah, that's odd. I'm using the same code and am getting zeros from val().length...

Comment: Ugh...forgot I wasn't using a textarea, I'm using a contenteditable div. val() returns 0, while text() returns the length, but it doesn't see the line breaks. :(

Comment: Dang you're using conenteditable div's?  Way to be ballsy.  I haven't ventured into them quite yet.

Comment: I ended up using this.innerHTML.length, which seems to be working. :)

Comment: It would be a good idea to save the entire text, not only the length, because it is possible to select a single character and replace it so the length will not change.