# jQuery KeyUp for @

Tags: jquery, click, keycode, keyup

How can I use

```
$('div').bind('keyup', function(e) {

   if(e.which == '@') {

   }

});
```

Wondering how I can get the `@` symbol for `keyup` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977642/how-to-know-if-keyup-is-a-character-key-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `String.fromCharCode` method. The reverse function is `"@".charCodeAt(0)`.
The `e.which` will only hold sensible data about the pressed key at a `keypress` event. This event will trigger multiple times though, while a key is pressed down.

If you need a reliable method to check the character of a key during the `keyup` event, create a character map. [This page](http://asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html) will aid you.

```
$('div').bind('keypress', function(e) {
   var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
   if(char == '@') {

   }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work, key codes for characters can vary by locale.  For example, English (UK) '@' is on key 192, along with `'`.

Comment: @AndyE `ev.which` shows `64` at the `keypress` event. Improved answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try yourself before post such question

Go to [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) and do a simple test:

> http://jsbin.com/afapar/2/edit#javascript,html,live

Then you will know exactly what to look for.

---

by the way, because you need to worry about plenty on all mobile devices and browsers, I will suggest that you use `indexOf()` or a variant of it, for example:

```
$("#txt").bind("keyup", function(evt) {
   if( $(this).val().indexOf("@") > 0 ) {
       // got it
   }
});
```

or if you need to know if it's the last character written:

```
if( $(this).val().lastIndexOf("@") == $(this).val().length - 1) 
{
    // got it
}
```

Comment: @balexandre - unfortunately using $.val() is no longer reliable in a html5 spec.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be working..
http://jsfiddle.net/jNeH9/2/

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
   if(e.which == 50 && e.shiftKey)
   {

   }

});
```

Comment: Maybe for your locale/keyboard layout, but definitely not for mine.