# How to extract special keys in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am calling `.keyup` function of Search Textbox, and in that `keyup()`, I am refreshing the GRID from the database.

**Problem:**

But the grid is getting refreshed for (special keys too ) arrow keys, number lock,function keys and all other keys and refreshing for those keys are unnecessary. Except backspace, return,tab,space,delete.

I want to construct a regular expression such that it filters out all  the control keys.

**Sample code:**

```js
$('#searchContent').keyup(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if ( /*condition*/ ) {
        return;
    }
    //my code goes here...
}
```

**What I have done:**

Searched net thoroughly and I came up with [hotkey](https://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/downloads/detail?name=jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.zip), but that doesn't solved my purpose. So, any smart regular expression are there?

Comment: Maybe you should use the `onchange` event?

Comment: @RJo `onchange` only triggers on blur afaik.

Comment: @Rjo yes now only I noticed that what Jack said.

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977642/how-to-know-if-keyup-is-a-character-key-jquery

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT Which keys DO need to trigger the grid refresh.

Comment: You could store the current value somewhere and then on each keystroke compare to the new value to see if it has changed...

Comment: @Mark Walters any alpha numeric, punctuation's, ctrl+v,shift+ins,and any keys that could possibly retrive differnt information from database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML to see which codes match up with which keys (taken from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.charCode#Notes)):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>charCode example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function showChar(e)
        {
            alert("Key Pressed: " + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode) + "\n"
                  + "charCode: " + e.charCode);
        }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body onkeypress="showChar(event);">
        <p>Press any 'character' type key.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But the `keypress` event as currently used in this answer may not trigger for delete or backspace...

Comment: it will fail in chrome and id incase of delete or backspace

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick:

```
function checkForChanges(){
   var txt = $('#searchContent');
   if(txt.val() != txt.attr('xvalue') {
      //do referesh grid content here
   }
}

$('#searchContent').keyup(function (e) {
    $(this).attr('xvalue') = this.value;    
    clearTimeout(this.changeTimer);    
    this.changeTimer = setTimeout(checkForChanges, 20);
}
```