# How to detect first character of input on keypress()

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I'm using jquery's function [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) for my input field

Now, let's say that I want to know when the user types a letter, if this is the first character in the field. I now use something like:

```
element.keypress(function(e){
    //...
    if(elementValue.length()==0){
        //Do something
    }
}
```

The problem is when the user selects the text that typed and then presses a key (lets say for the character 'A') that **replaces** it. Then this code returns the length of the old-(soon to be replaced) text.

I know that I could use **keyup** instead, but I think I need to stay with keypress because I have to do some checks for the pressed physical keys. ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3978257/2667686) really shows the difference between keyup and keypress in this case)

Any suggestions?

Comment: [_selectionStart_, _selectionEnd_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) (applies to `<input>` and `<textarea>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Paul S. put me in the right direction...

That's what I have now and it works:

```
element.keypress(function(e){
    //...
    if(this.selectionStart==0){
        //Do something
    }
}
```

This way I detect when a key has been pressed while the caret was just at the beginning of the field.