# Detect backspace and special characters using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, key

I want to detect these two behaviours on an input field:

1)Backspace key

2)"@" and "#" key

By using jQuery's `keypress` function, I am able to detect the special characters but not backspace.
LINK -> [How to know if .keyup() is a character key (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977642/how-to-know-if-keyup-is-a-character-key-jquery)

By using jQuery's `keyup`/`keydown`, I am able to detect backspace, but not special characters. 
LINK -> [jQuery: keyPress Backspace won't fire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690330/jquery-keypress-backspace-wont-fire)

How can I detect both the behaviours ?

NOTE: `Keypress` can detect backspace in firefox only. Chrome doesn't detect this.

Comment: What's wrong with keyup event? Not sure to understand your issue. Could you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: With that, I cannot detect backspace on chrome. (check the link provided)

Comment: `keypress` isn't fired for backspace, `keyup` is. My question was regarding `keyup`. So what's wrong with using `keyup`??? Test it yourself here: http://jsfiddle.net/8W7uV/  EDIT: ok, i see now what you mean by "special keys"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following snippet:

```
var keys = {};

$('input').keydown(function (e) {
    keys[e.which] = true;
});

$('input').keyup(function (e) {        
    getKeys();
    delete keys[e.which];    
});

function getKeys() {    
   if(keys[8]) {
        alert('bakspace pressed');
    }else if(keys[17] && keys[18] && keys[48]) {
        alert('@ pressed');
    }else if(keys[17] && keys[18] && keys[51]) {
        alert('# pressed');
    }    
}
```

### DEMO

original post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954480/1414562

Comment: This won't work if i want to write in between 2 words. For example: "hey there" is already there, but i try to enter @sam in between "hey" and "there". Any ideas ?

Comment: @user2962766 Updated answer to handle this case

Comment: Now @ key is not detected.