# Identify paste text and type text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to know if text to an input field was added by typing or by using paste?

```
$('document').on("keyup", ".tfs", function(e) {
   alert("typed text");
})

$('.tfs').on('paste', function(e) {
   alert("paste text!");
});
```

**EDIT:**
I'm looking for an solution which is not an inline code solution such as `onpaste()`. I'm need to do this using `bind` ( `.on` now ) as per my code above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intercept paste event in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035071/intercept-paste-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Your code shud work.

Comment: @EvanKnowles: I came across that post while googling. Inline `onpaste` is not the solution I'm seeking. I'm finding a solution using `bind` (`.on` now)

Comment: Most browsers support the `paste event` on forms and text inputs, but not all on window or document. So you have to bind it to the input element. [reference](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are `'`s around `document`. Remove them or use this code -

```
$('.tfs').on("keypress", function(e) {
   alert("typed text");
})

$('.tfs').on('paste', function(e) {
   alert("paste text!");
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9dcvajb9/)

The `keypress` event will allow to check for characters not arrows or backspace etc.

[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977642/how-to-know-if-keyup-is-a-character-key-jquery)

Comment: thanks. why doesn't my one work when `$('document').on` is used instead of `$('.tfs').on` for type text?

Comment: It was the `'`s around `document`

Answer (score 1):

something may help

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#textA").bind({
        copy : function(){
            $('span').text('copy behaviour detected!');
        },
        paste : function(){
            $('span').text('paste behaviour detected!');
        },
        cut : function(){
            $('span').text('cut behaviour detected!');
        }
    });

});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/1mnc4kb3/)